# scope of struct pointers in functions

Tags: c, pointers, struct, heap-memory, function-pointers

If i have the following in a function:

```
struct example *A=malloc(sizeof(struct example));
```

does the node/memory space created where A points to get destroyed after the function ends/leaves? Or does it stay in the heap?

Comment: when function terminates *A(pointer) on stack gets destroyed but , memory allocated to *A is still there. As this memory is having no longer valid pointer, its out of system memory structure ie called memory leak. So you must use free() always with malloc();

Answer (score 1):

No.  memory allocated by `malloc` will stay allocated until `free`'d.

Doing things like this:

```
char * function(void)
{
    char c = 'a';
    return &c;
}
```

on the other hand, is bad, because this object DOES go out of scope when the function ends.

`malloc` allocates memory on the heap.  Declaring variables allocates space on the stack.  The stack is affected by scope, the heap is not.

For additional information about the use of pointers, including various gotchas such as memory leaks (the process of losing a reference to `malloc`'d memory such that it persists forever), visit [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-toughgame/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to `free` everything that you `malloc`. When your function returns, the variable `A` goes out of scope, but your memory stays allocated. As you have lost the pointer to the memory (unless stored elsewhere) you are [leaking memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

If you still need the memory pointed to by `A`, you could return the pointer to the allocated struct, and free it later. If you don't need the allocated memory once your function returns, free the memory with `free(A)`.